# How to remove the quotes while converting a file from sql to tbl

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is the code which converts the .sql file for insert statements into .tbl file. As the input file is .sql file it contains varchar(string) values inside single quotes. How can I prevent these quotes from getting in my tbl file?

**Input:**

```
INSERT INTO 
post_tran(post_tran_id,tran_nr,datetime_tran_local,system_trace_audit_nr,settle_
amount_rsp,settle_tran_fee_rsp,post_tran_cust_id,prev_post_tran_id,next_post_tra
n_id,message_type,tran_postilion_originated,sink_node_name,settle_entity_id,batc
h_nr,tran_completed,tran_type,rsp_code_rsp,auth_type,auth_reason,retrieval_refer
ence_nr,settle_amount_req,settle_tran_fee_req,settle_currency_code,datetime_req,
recon_business_date,realtime_business_date,acquiring_inst_id_code) VALUES( 
1,2,'2002-04-02 19:02:28','008497',4120,10, 2, 0,0,'0200', 0, 'LinkSink', 
1,1,0,'01','01','00',0,'000000000102',6000,0,'840', '', '2004-02-11 
12:00:00', '2004-02-11 12:00:00', '2200017000')
```

**For example:**
While processing sink_node_name, its data value should be `LinkSink` instead of `'LinkSink'`.

```
public class SqlToTblCoverter {

    private File source_folder = null;
    private File destination_folder = null;
    private String source_absolute_path = null;
    private String destination_absolute_path = null;
    private String absolute_file_name = null;
    private String absolute_new_file_name = null;
    private List<String> column_name_list = null;
    private List<String> column_values_list = null;

    public SqlToTblCoverter(String source_folder_name,
            String destination_folder_name) {
        source_folder = new File(source_folder_name);
        destination_folder = new File(destination_folder_name);
        source_absolute_path = source_folder.getAbsolutePath();
        destination_absolute_path = destination_folder.getAbsolutePath();
        column_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        column_values_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void run() throws IOException {
        validateInputs();
        migrateFiles();
    }

    private void validateInputs() {
        if (source_folder.isDirectory() == false) {
            System.out.println("Source must be a FOLDER");
        } else if (destination_folder.isDirectory() == false) {
            System.out.println("Destination must be a FOLDER");
        }
    }

    private void migrateFiles() throws IOException {
        String[] file_list = source_folder.list();
        String file_name1 = file_list[0];
        // System.out.println(file_name1);

        String file_name2 = file_list[1];
        // System.out.println(file_name2);

        String f1 = migrateFileContains(file_name1);
        String f2 = migrateFileContains(file_name2);

        Migrator mg = new Migrator();
        mg.migrate(f1, f2);
    }

    private String migrateFileContains(String file_name) throws IOException {
        absolute_file_name = source_absolute_path + File.separator + file_name;
        absolute_new_file_name = destination_absolute_path + File.separator
                + getNewFileName(file_name);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(new File(absolute_file_name))));
        String line_info = br.readLine();
        StringBuffer new_query = new StringBuffer("");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(absolute_new_file_name));
        while (line_info != null) {
            String convertQuery = convertQuery(line_info);
            if (convertQuery.isEmpty()) {
                line_info = br.readLine();
                continue;
            }
            new_query.append(convertQuery);
            new_query.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fw.write(new_query.toString());
            new_query.setLength(0);
            line_info = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        fw.close();
        return absolute_new_file_name;

    }

    private String convertQuery(String query) {
        String new_query = "";
        if (query.startsWith("INSERT")) {
            int round_bracket_start = query.indexOf('(');
            int round_bracket_end = query.indexOf(')');
            int round_bracket_start_after_values = query.indexOf('(',
                    round_bracket_end);
            String query_column_name = query.substring(round_bracket_start + 1,
                    round_bracket_end);
            String query_column_values = query.substring(
                    round_bracket_start_after_values + 1, query.length() - 1);
            covertColumnNameList(query_column_name);
            covertColumnValueList(',' + query_column_values + ',');
            new_query = createNewQuery() + "\n";
        }
        column_name_list.clear();
        column_values_list.clear();
        return new_query;
    }

    private void covertColumnNameList(String query_column_name) {
        String[] column_list = query_column_name.split(",");
        for (String column_name : column_list) {
            column_name_list.add(column_name);
        }
    }

    private void covertColumnValueList(String query_column_values) {
        if (query_column_values.equals(",")) {
            return;
        }
        String column_value = null;
        int comma_index = query_column_values.indexOf(',');
        int next_comma_index = 0;
        if (query_column_values.charAt(comma_index + 1) == '\'') {
            int quote_index = query_column_values.indexOf('\'', comma_index);
            int next_quote_index = query_column_values.indexOf('\'',
                    quote_index + 1);
            next_comma_index = query_column_values.indexOf(',',
                    next_quote_index);
            column_value = query_column_values.substring(comma_index + 2,
                    next_comma_index - 1);
        } else {
            next_comma_index = query_column_values
                    .indexOf(',', comma_index + 1);
            column_value = query_column_values.substring(comma_index + 1,
                    next_comma_index);
        }
        column_values_list.add(column_value);
        covertColumnValueList(query_column_values.substring(next_comma_index));
    }

    private String createNewQuery() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
        if (column_name_list.size() != column_values_list.size()) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + absolute_file_name);
        } else {
            for (int index = 0; index < column_name_list.size(); index++) {
                buffer.append(createNewColumn(column_name_list.get(index),
                        column_values_list.get(index)));
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private String createNewColumn(String column_name, String column_value) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
        buffer.append("[name]".trim());
        buffer.append(column_name.trim());
        buffer.append("[/name]=[data]".trim());
        buffer.append(column_value.trim());
        buffer.append("[/data]".trim());
        buffer.append("\r\n");
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private String getNewFileName(String file_name) {
        String new_file_name = "";
        int dot_index = file_name.indexOf('.');
        new_file_name = file_name.subSequence(0, dot_index) + ".tbl";
        return new_file_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `''`? Replaced by empty string?

Comment: @Gosu Then a comma between apostrophes will cause havoc.

Comment: @Gosu ' ' should be replaced by the current date of the system. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace covertColumnValueList with below code:

```
private void covertColumnValueList(String query_column_values) {
    String temp_val = null;

    for (String col_val : query_column_values.split(",")) {

        if (col_val.contains("\'")) {
            temp_val = col_val.replaceAll("\'", "");
            column_values_list.add(temp_val.trim());
        } else
            column_values_list.add(col_val.trim());
    }
}
```

I assume you have query_column_values something like below:

String query_column_values = "1,2,'2002-04-02 19:02:28','008497',4120,10, 2, 0,0,'0200', 0, 'LinkSink', 1,1,0,'01','01','00',0,'000000000102',6000,0,'840', '', '2004-02-11 12:00:00', '2004-02-11 12:00:00', '2200017000'";

**replace '' by current date**: Once you populate this list, replace list value at specified index.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");        
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
column_values_list.set( 23, dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thank You. But I also want to replace '' by current date. How should I do that?

Comment: @DownVoters Why don't you put a comment - to understand what makes you  think something not right.

Comment: Splitting the string at ',' is contrary to the original code that takes care to keep commas in a value enclosed between apostrophes. True, the input sample has no such value, but one should never base code on a single data sample. @user3678383 you should not use this code *unless you are sure that commas never appear in field values*.

Comment: And, second point: do you really think that `''` is always at index position 23?

Comment: Column values are always at fixed index...so @user3678383 should be knowing correct index. You are right about additional comma's in data...this code need to be modified to handle such cases.

Comment: So this table will never be changed? And what about using this code with another table?

Answer (score 0):

The code to remove the delimiting apostrophes is there in covertColumnValueList, but it doesn't handle the case where a space precedes the apostroph. See the simple fix below.

```
//....
int next_comma_index = 0;
// skip space(s)
while( query_column_values.charAt(comma_index + 1) == ' ' ){
    comma_index++;
}
if (query_column_values.charAt(comma_index + 1) == '\'') {
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void covertColumnValueList(String query_column_values) {
if (query_column_values.equals(",")) {
    return;
}
String column_value = null;
int comma_index = query_column_values.indexOf(',');
int next_comma_index = 0;
if (query_column_values.charAt(comma_index + 1) == '\'') {
    int quote_index = query_column_values.indexOf('\'', comma_index);
    int next_quote_index = query_column_values.indexOf('\'',
            quote_index + 1);
    next_comma_index = query_column_values.indexOf(',',
            next_quote_index);
    column_value = query_column_values.substring(comma_index + 2,
            next_comma_index - 1);
 column_value=column_value.replace("\'","") ;
} else {
    next_comma_index = query_column_values
            .indexOf(',', comma_index + 1);
    column_value = query_column_values.substring(comma_index + 1,
            next_comma_index);
   column_value=column_value.replace("\'","") ;
}
column_values_list.add(column_value);
covertColumnValueList(query_column_values.substring(next_comma_index));
}
```